# Excel power query, 1 row of multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, powerquery

hope you can help me.

I recently stumbled across excel power query, but I’m not getting too far with it.

I’m trying to pull data from around 40 workbooks in the same folder. Each workbook has 2 sheets , but the only sheet I’m concerned with is sheet 1. Row 1 of each sheet 1 has a summary of the data I need, so I only need row 1 x 40,

There are no tables on the workbooks, it’s just some basic data, however, row 1 contains a sum formula in each of the 20 columns.

Is this doable? I have to manually copy and paste each row 1 into a master every week.

Thanks very much if you can help.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49248840

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response , however I get this error 

Expression error The import Table.TransformColumns matches no exports. Did you miss a module reference?

Comment: A typo when I was inputting!! It worked, thank you so much, you have saved me so much time! 

Many thanks Aleksei, and good health to you in these times.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, column names in all files are the same and you wish to keep filenames:

```
let
    Source = Folder.Files(YourFolder),
    transform = Table.TransformColumns(Source, {"Content", each Table.FirstN(Excel.Workbook(_){[Item="Sheet1"]}[Data],1)})[[Content],[Name]],
    expand = Table.ExpandTableColumn(transform, "Content", Table.ColumnNames(transform[Content]{0}))
in
    expand
```